# PostgreSQL - How to make join query using four tables?

Tags: postgresql, left-join, inner-join

I have a tables like these:

**code_number:**
ID,
cnumber,
name,
status,
program_id

```
id        cnumber    name     status     program_id
33051     1234561    ABC      NEW          32751
33052     1234562    XYZ      NEW          32751
```

**pocket:**
ID,
name,
amount,
type,
cnumber_id,
program_id,
customer_id

```
id       name      amount    type       cnumber_id program_id    customer_id
44546    personal  €1,40     PERSONAL    33051    32751         6612
44547    partner   €214,14   RECHARGE    33051    32751         6612
44548    discount            DISCOUNT    33051    32751         6612
51172    personal  €12,40    PERSONAL    33052    32751         6644
51173    partner   €54,50    RECHARGE    33052    32751         6644
51174    discount  €0,50     DISCOUNT    33052    32751         6644
51175    saving    €190,50   SAVING      33052    32751         6644
```

**customer:**
ID,
customer_name,
program_id

```
id      customer_name       program_id
6612    shop1               32751
6644    shop2               32751
```

**transaction:**
ID,
time,
amount,
status,
type,
customer_id,
cnumber_id,
program_id,
pocket_id

```
id      time                 type            status     amount  customer_id cnumber_id   program_id pocket_id
82420   16/05/202115:18:22  Saving          PROCCESSED  -€0,02  6612        33051      32751       null
82419   16/05/2021 15:18:22 Personal        PROCCESSED   €0,02  6612        33051      32751       null
82418   16/05/2021 15:18:22 ContraPayment   PROCCESSED   €0,30  6612        33051      32751       null
82417   16/05/2021 15:18:22 Payment         PROCCESSED  -€0,30  6612        33051      32751       null
82416   16/05/2021 13:12:25 Saving          PROCCESSED  -€0,02  6644        33052      32751       null
82415   16/05/2021 13:12:25 Personal        PROCCESSED   €0,02  6644        33052      32751       null
82414   16/05/2021 13:12:25 ContraPayment   PROCCESSED   €0,50  6644        33052      32751       null
82413   16/05/2021 13:12:25 Payment         PROCCESSED  -€0,50  6644        33052      32751       null
```

pocket_id is getting null in list of transaction. How can I achieve below list using these four table?  I need query which is display p_type for each transaction.

**`TR_ID, Tr_Time, TR_type, TR_status, Tr_amount, customer_name, P_type, cnumber, program_id`**

I am beginner to create query but I have tries below query. I can not join customer table otherwise records are getting double.

```
SELECT 
tr.id as tr_id,
tr.time as tr_date,  
tr.amount as tr_amount, 
tr.type as tr_type,
tr.status as tr_status, 
po.cnumber_id as cnumber_id, 
po.customer_id as customer_id, 
po.type as p_type,
cn.name as customer_name,
c.cnumber as cnumber,
tr.program_id as program_id from transaction tr
left join pocket po  on tr.pocket_id= po.id 
left join code_number c on c.id = po.cnumber_id 
left join customer cn on c.id = po.customer_id
where tr.program_id= 32751 and tr.status= 'NEW';
```

Thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42CFA.jpg)

Comment: I made join query but there are multiple records.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the query you tried, and how it had the wrong result.

Comment: I have edited my question. Hope I will get query depends on transaction data with  pocket type, cnumber and customer name....

Comment: How did you try to join the customers in there? And please tell us what your schema is structured, otherwise we cannot give a meaningful answer. Why do all tables have a program_id? Why do both the transaction and the pocket tables have customer and cnumber references, but the transaction also references a pocket?

Comment: I have updated the query and added image.

Comment: Is there anyone can solve this issue?

Comment: I cannot reproduce with the data you've given. Rows are doubled in a JOIN if the joined table has duplicate rows, i.e. there are two customer records with the same id. But given the id column is a primary key in your schema, this cannot happen.